# Is there anyway to ignore the CMOS Check during Startup?

Tags: boot, bios, secure-boot, cmos

I have broken my CMOS battery seat while replacing the battery, and I want to my pc to Ignore Cmos check during startup.

I have already turned on fast boot, but everytime I turn off the switch, fast boot fails due to CMOS check, but works as long as my power is turned on.

I want Bios to ignore CMOS check as it is taking 1min more to boot everytime I turn off the switch.

Is there a way to do so ?, because I really don't need CMOS for date & time as my pc automatically synchronises it with internet as soon as it gets connected.

Comment: Unlikely.  That said, you might want to advise the motherboard model, and what exactly you mean by "CMOS port"

Comment: You probably broke the seat for the CMOS battery. You're lucky the motherboard still boots when under power.

Comment: @davidgo , It is a software related question, what's the need of  mother board?

Comment: If you could tell the computer not to do checks at boot it would store that in its configuration, that bios config is maintained by the CMOS battery; so as there's no battery it will reset the bios config and forget that you want to ignore the check. Perhaps the bios checks can be reprogrammed, but a new mobo is probably cheaper than the chip programming tool.

Comment: When you are dealing with the BIOS **you are not dealing with software.**  You might be dealing with firmware - this is specific to the power supply.  BIOS kicks in before the OS or boot loader is loaded - and indeed this is what kicks off running any software, so you can't fix it in software because it runs before software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only reset your CMOS through the BIOS but you cannot disable it.

You can try buying and installing a new [CMOS Battery Holder](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/battery-holders/7188472?cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_UK_EN_Batteries_%26_Chargers_Whoop-_-Battery%20Holders_Whoop_OMNISerpNov-_-7188472&matchtype=&aud-827186183686:pla-338046783069&gclid=Cj0KCQjwma6TBhDIARIsAOKuANxNEar6t17dIiGyAIxhhQwEz6BofNxmsnmDvdcy41VGZMLrU-AK_3IaAuVzEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) or using some sort of [DIY method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hR5Qq3zPXv8) to fix it (at your own risk).

Comment: I was going to post that same DIY method link, but you already beat me to it. In the video he just ties the wires to the old clips. That's fine (soldering isn't really needed for this if the wires make good contact), but I would additionally wrap a little electrical tape around them just to make sure they won't come loose and accidentally short circuit something.